# How to add a file into an already existing dataTransfer object using Javascript

Tags: javascript, file, drag-and-drop, data-transfer, data-transfer-objects

Assumption: A local HTML/Javascript webpage that has access to file://

At the start of a drag on a draggable HTML element, in the event handler function `dragStart(e)`, how do I add a File object so that it is recognized as a file and ends up in the `dataTransfer.files` list?

Ex:

```
function dragStart(e){
    var file = getSomeFileObjFromSomewhere();
    e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = "all";
    e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.setData("file", file);

    console.log("\nFiles:");
    i = 0;
    var files = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files,
    len = files.length;
    for (; i < len; i++) {
        console.log("\nIndex: " + i + "\nFilename: " + files[i].name);
        console.log("Type: " + files[i].type);
        console.log("Size: " + files[i].size + " bytes");
        console.dir(files[i]);
    }
}
```

Specifically, it needs to work on Chrome/Chromium. And, we can assume that the file exists on the local drive. Basically, I want the same data available then when a file is dragged from Windows Explorer to a HTML page on an element that is droppable.

I know that this exists in Chrome:

```
e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.setData("DownloadURL", fileType + ":" + name + ":" + filePath);
```

which downloads the file. But this is not what I want, because I want to assume that this is an existing file and that the original file must be accessed.

Comment: I doubt this can be done. If I understand correctly you're essentially asking the browser to upload someone's file without them initiating the file transfer. I can't see browsers allowing that to happen - it would be a security flaw

Comment: If you are able to get file at `var file = getSomeFileObjFromSomewhere();` what is purpose of setting file object at `event.dataTransfer`? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @KScandrett - the File object would have to be generated from things already accessible to Javascript (including File objects generated explicitly by user interaction with a file input)

Comment: I am trying to achieve generating a file from one page that can be dragged by the user into another page, like they would drag a file from their file system into that other page

Comment: What do you mean by "another page"? [Drag and drop images, and not links, between windows - HTML5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41388434/drag-and-drop-images-and-not-links-between-windows-html5/)?

Comment: _"like they would drag a file from their file system into that other page"_ Do you mean drag and drop between two `html` documents? Or drag a file from user file manager UI at OS to an `html` document?

Comment: @FabioBeltramini Can you provide further description as to what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: From a dragstart event in one html page/document/window, attach a JS-generated file-object to the event in such a way that the user can drop it into another window, and that window recognizes the attached file, just as if the user had dragged it from their file system

Comment: In my scenario, the target page exists and listens for file drops, I can't edit it, I just want to make a tool for building and passing in compatible files

Comment: Example scenario: generate a CSV file using the "File" object, and store it in the drag object, as if the user dragged a file from their filesystem. This is useful to unify some workflows.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the approach posted by @kol at [Simulate drop file event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22365796/simulate-drop-file-event)

> That is, we have to pass an argument to ondrop, which
>
> - has a `dataTransfer` field with a `files` array subfield, which contains the selected `File`, and
> - a `preventDefault` method (a function with no body will do).

adjusted below to attach `.addEventListener("drop")` to `drop` element at `dragstart` event, with `File` objects passed to a bound function with `Function.prototype.bind()` which returns the appropriate object described above, with `once:true` passed at third parameter to `.addEventListener()`, to call `drop` event at most once for each `dragstart` event where `File` objects are accessed or created.

[`FileList`](https://w3c.github.io/FileAPI/#filelist-section) object is read only, an `Array` is used to store `File` object at `dataTransfer.files` property within a plain `javascript` object at event handlers.

> Note: The [`FileList`](https://w3c.github.io/FileAPI/#dfn-filelist) interface should be considered "at risk"
>   since the general trend on the Web Platform is to replace such
>   interfaces with the [`Array`](http://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-array-constructor) platform object in ECMAScript
>   [[ECMA-262]](https://w3c.github.io/FileAPI/#biblio-ecma-262). In particular, this means syntax of the sort
>   `filelist.item(0)` is at risk; most other programmatic use of
>   `FileList` is unlikely to be affected by the eventual migration to an
>   `Array` type.

If `event.dataTransfer.files` at `dragstart` event contains `File` objects, iterate `FileList` and push each `File` object to `files` array.

```js
var drag = document.getElementById("drag")
var drop = document.getElementById("drop")

function handleDrop(evt) {
  evt.preventDefault();
  console.log(evt.dataTransfer.files);
}

function getSomeFileObjFromSomewhere() {
  var data = ["abc", "def"];
  var files = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    files.push(new File([data[i]], data[i] + ".text", {
      type: "text/plain",
      lastModified: new Date().getTime()
    }));
  }
  return files
}

function dataTransferFileObject(files) {
  return {
    preventDefault: function() {},
    dataTransfer: {
      files: Array.isArray(files) ? files : [files]
    }
  }
}

drag.addEventListener("dragstart", function dragStart(e) {

  var files = getSomeFileObjFromSomewhere();
  e.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = "all";

  console.log("\nFiles:");
  
  for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    var {name, size, type} = files[i];
    console.log("\nFilename: " + name);
    console.log("Type: " + type);
    console.log("Size: " + size + " bytes");
  }
  // if `e.dataTransfer.files`, push `File` objects dragged
  // to `files` array
  if (e.dataTransfer.files) {
    for (let file of e.dataTransfer.files) {
      files.push(file);
    }
  }
  
  drop.addEventListener("drop"
  , handleDrop.bind(drop, dataTransferFileObject(files))
  , {once: true});

});

drop.addEventListener("dragover", function(evt) {
  evt.preventDefault()
});
```

```css
div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
}

div:nth-child(1) {
  border: 2px dotted blue;
}

div:nth-child(2) {
  border: 2px dotted green;
}
```

```html
<div draggable="true" id="drag">drag</div>
<div droppable="true" id="drop" webkitdropzone="webkitdropzone">drop</div>
```

plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/ihQqs4t2zOg2XhIuNwal?p=preview

Comment: Thanks, this seems like progress! It appears to work when viewed from within the dragstart event, but the dataTransfer items/files don't seem to persist through to the drop event. Or am I doing something wrong there? http://plnkr.co/edit/H5gfm82JZGRuEuDIM7WM?p=preview

Comment: @FabioBeltramini Note, the Question does not actually mention `drop` event.

Comment: Ok, regarding the drop event, perhaps I read too much into this phrase "I want the same data available [as] when a file is dragged from Windows Explorer to a HTML page on an element that is droppable". But lets see if this new plkr helps

Comment: The drop listener on the new pluker isn't checking the dataTransfer files. It's seeming like there is no way to attach files to the dataTransfer such that the drop event can receive them as files?

Comment: You can pass a data URI at setData and use getData at drop event. Though FileReader load event returns results asynchronously.

Comment: I will award you the bounty (as the only answer). Unfortunately, clever as this may be, it still doesn't help me, as I cannot modify the drop listener because it is on another page.

Comment: @FabioBeltramini _"Note: Dragging files can currently only happen from outside a [browsing context](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/browsers.html#browsing-context), for example from a file system manager application."_ [7.7.5 Drag-and-drop processing model](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/dnd.html#drag-and-drop-processing-model). Though you can use `.setData()`, `.getData()` approach to transfer `data URI` representation of file, see `console` at http://plnkr.co/edit/zmyRoA11W4iMl7m8TIPS?p=preview. Note also, approach at http://stackoverflow.com/a/41388593/

Comment: @FabioBeltramini Have you considered posting a new Question including full  context and requirements described at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24496989/how-to-add-a-file-into-an-already-existing-datatransfer-object-using-javascript/42562239#comment72329852_24496989, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24496989/how-to-add-a-file-into-an-already-existing-datatransfer-object-using-javascript/42562239#comment72329999_24496989 , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24496989/how-to-add-a-file-into-an-already-existing-datatransfer-object-using-javascript/42562239#comment72390503_42562239 ?

Comment: Yes, I was planning on doing so once this bounty expired. However, your link to w3 helps to establish that the answer to my question would be "currently not possible". Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

The simplest way is by "add item":

```
const dataTransfer = new DataTransfer();
const aFileParts = ['<a id="a"><b id="b">hey!</b></a>'];
dataTransfer.items.add(new File([new Blob(aFileParts, { type: 'text/html' })], 'test.txt'));
```

Only what u need it's adjust your file to file type :)

Comment: What the constant aFileParts is doing in this code  ? I don't understand its functionnality...

Comment: It is just a mock because `new Blob()` requires this param. You can create there whatever you want :)

Comment: Yes, that's true. In my case, it was an "already created" blob so I just had to pass it in newFile().

Comment: Then `dataTransfer.types` is `[text/plain]`, while when dragging a real file from the file browser it is `[Files]`.