# Drag and drop images, and not links, between windows - HTML5

Tags: javascript, html, url, file-upload, droppable

I'm trying to make a drag and drop uploader in HTML5 with the added requirement of being able to do so with files dragged from other websites I don't own and can't edit (mostly images).

In this case, on the `ondrop` event, instead of downloading the image from the local computer using `e.dataTransfer.files` and posting it, I retrieve the URL with `e.dataTransfer.getData('URL')` and post it to the server for it to download server-side.

Works fines, except when I drag an image enclosed in a link.

It works when initiating drag from an `<img>` element, but not with an `<img>` enclosed in `<a>` element. In the latter one, `e.dataTransfer.getData('URL')` gives me the `href` of the link, not the `src` of the image.

I looked into `e.dataTransfer.getData()` to see if it accepted other arguments that could help. The other alternative was "Text", and it brought up the same results as "URL".

Is there a way to get the image URL or am I doomed because the browser doesn't actualy carry the image URL when dragging an image enclosed in a link (ie : I'm dragging the link, not the image)?

#### UPDATE

To illustrate I created a jsfiddle here : https://jsfiddle.net/2m58rfou/
And another one with 2 images to demonstrate my problem here : https://jsfiddle.net/870asboa/
Open them in separate tabs and try dragging both images in the drop zone.

With the first image, I get what I want : `https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/1.sm.jpg`
With the second one I get `http://www.google.com/`, the link the image is enclosed in, rather than the image address.

In the second scenario, is there a way to get the image address and not the link in the `ondrop` listenner, or is it impossible ? (remember that the images can be on any website, I can't catch any `dragstart` event, basically only the `drop` one).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At `dragover` event handler, iterating [`event.dataTransfer.types`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransfer/types)

> The `DataTransfer.types` read-only property is an array of the drag
>   data formats (as strings) that were set in the `dragstart` event. The
>   order of the formats is the same order as the data included in the
>   drag operation.

the array contains three `types`:

- `text/plain`
- `text/uri-list`
- `text/html`

`text/html` is the `html` string of the dragged `<img>` element.

Get the string using by passing `"text/html"` to `.getData()`, then either extract `src` of `html` string using `RegExp` or create an element and append the `html` string to the element, then get `src` of `<img>` element using `.src`.

```
holder.ondrop = function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();       
  this.className = '';
  var img = e.dataTransfer.getData("text/html");
  var div = document.createElement("div");
  div.innerHTML = img;
  var src = div.firstChild.src;
  console.log(div.firstChild, src);
  results.innerText = src;
}
```

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/2m58rfou/6/

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. But this only works for pages I own.

Comment: @noodlesup Not certain what you mean? Open a separate tab, load a new jsfiddle editor including `<teaxtarea>` element. Drag image from jsfiddle link at Answer and drop dragged image at `<textarea>` at separate tab.

Comment: This only works on pages where I can run this script, pages I own and can edit. How can I get this behavior from external websites ?

Comment: You can get the `src` of all images within `document` at `console` using `document.images`.

Comment: I don't think you understand what I'm saying. I can't use ondragstart because the drag starts from another website in another tab.

Comment: If you are not the owner of the `document` you can use `console` at the tab to retrieve the `src` of all images. You could also probably set `dragstart` event to all images on page at `console`. Else, get all `img` element `src` using `document.images`. See [List file sizes of all images on a page (Chrome Extension)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41085017/list-file-sizes-of-all-images-on-a-page-chrome-extension)

Comment: @noodlesup You could also right-click on the image and select `Copy image address`, then paste the `<img>` `src` at another tab.

Comment: Sure, or I could download the image and then upload it. The point is doing it with a drag and drop from another website.

Comment: @noodlesup If you are not the owner of the `document`, how is this to be achieved? Have you tried attaching `dragstart` event and handler at Answer to `<img>` elements   at `console`?

Comment: @noodlesup _"How can I get this behavior from external websites ?"_  Have you considered including that you are trying to achieve requirement at `document` which you do not control `javascript` at Question?

Comment: You're right I didn't make it clear. I updated the question and also added a jsfiddle.

Comment: @noodlesup Re-read update, you did include some details concerning the site where you want to drag the image from. Though is using `console` or approach other than drag and drop possibility?

Comment: Not sure if this is possible using drag and drop alone without being able to modify which element is being dragged or explicitly setting the data to be transferred. Workarounds could be possible. One workaround is to right-click the image, select `Open image in a new tab`, then drag the image to the drop area. Will update Answer with that approach.

Comment: Yes the `Open image in a new tab` is the simplest workaround. I was wondering if I could get past these extra clicks.

Comment: Not sure how you would go about that? Why make the process more complicated?

Comment: It's actually making the process simpler for the final user.

Comment: @noodlesup Another option is using copy/paste. Select `Copy image address` at first page, then paste the URL at element at second page. You can use `paste` event to catch the paste of image URL.See updated post.

Comment: I didn't kow about the `text/html` argument. `e.dataTransfer.getData("text/html")` absolutely works, thank you !