# How to convert a URL into an image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image

I am currently using the code below to detect if a URL is pasted into a contenteditable div. If a URL is pasted, it will automatically be converted into a link (surrounded by `a` tags).

How would I change this so that if the user pastes an image URL, it would be converted to `<img src="https://example.com/image.jpg">` whilst also converting non-image URL's to standard links (surrounded by `a` tags).

```
var saveSelection, restoreSelection;

if (window.getSelection && document.createRange) {
    saveSelection = function(containerEl) {
        var range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
        var preSelectionRange = range.cloneRange();
        preSelectionRange.selectNodeContents(containerEl);
        preSelectionRange.setEnd(range.startContainer, range.startOffset);
        var start = preSelectionRange.toString().length;

        return {
            start: start,
            end: start + range.toString().length
        }
    };


} else if (document.selection) {

}

function createLink(matchedTextNode) {
    var el = document.createElement("a");
    el.href = matchedTextNode.data;
    el.appendChild(matchedTextNode);
    return el;
}

function shouldLinkifyContents(el) {
    return el.tagName != "A";
}

function surroundInElement(el, regex, surrounderCreateFunc, shouldSurroundFunc) {
    var child = el.lastChild;
    while (child) {
        if (child.nodeType == 1 && shouldSurroundFunc(el)) {
            surroundInElement(child, regex, createLink, shouldSurroundFunc);
        } else if (child.nodeType == 3) {
            surroundMatchingText(child, regex, surrounderCreateFunc);
        }
        child = child.previousSibling;
    }
}

function surroundMatchingText(textNode, regex, surrounderCreateFunc) {
    var parent = textNode.parentNode;
    var result, surroundingNode, matchedTextNode, matchLength, matchedText;
    while ( textNode && (result = regex.exec(textNode.data)) ) {
        matchedTextNode = textNode.splitText(result.index);
        matchedText = result[0];
        matchLength = matchedText.length;
        textNode = (matchedTextNode.length > matchLength) ?
            matchedTextNode.splitText(matchLength) : null;
        surroundingNode = surrounderCreateFunc(matchedTextNode.cloneNode(true));
        parent.insertBefore(surroundingNode, matchedTextNode);
        parent.removeChild(matchedTextNode);
    }
}

var textbox = $('.editable')[0];
var urlRegex = /http(s?):\/\/($|[^\s]+)/;

function updateLinks() {
    var savedSelection = saveSelection(textbox);
    surroundInElement(textbox, urlRegex, createLink, shouldLinkifyContents);
    restoreSelection(textbox, savedSelection);
}

var $textbox = $(textbox);

$(document).ready(function () {
    $textbox.focus();

    var keyTimer = null, keyDelay = 1000;

    $textbox.keyup(function() {
        if (keyTimer) {
            window.clearTimeout(keyTimer);
        }
        keyTimer = window.setTimeout(function() {
            updateLinks();
            keyTimer = null;
        }, keyDelay);
    });
});
```

Comment: See [Drag and drop images, and not links, between windows - HTML5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41388434/drag-and-drop-images-and-not-links-between-windows-html5/)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to parse the pasted url, and search for ending extension (jpg,gif,png) ?

It should be simple, if the ending is matching one of those, then you wrap the url into an  href propriety.

Did You wrote this code by yourself?

Here you can read about strings methods to do this:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String