# Need a JavaScript "file" object without using a file chooser, for unit test

Tags: javascript, unit-testing

I need to unit test a number of functions on an object that is designed to hold a file.

However, as a part of setting up the unit test, I need to get my hands on an a file object in the same directory as the test.  This test is supposed to be run automatically, without ever loading a browser, and so can't be reliant on a user clicking a button to load the file.

Below is an example of a function I need to unit-test.

```
    getExtension: function () {
        return this.attributes.file.name.split(".").pop().toLowerCase();
    }
```

So can anyone tell me how to create that JavaScript file object without using the file chooser?

I'm using the Jasmine framework.

Edit:
I searched before I created this question, since I was earnestly trying to find an answer, but now that I've created it, I found another question with partial answers already on it:
[How to instantiate a File object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8390855/how-to-instantiate-a-file-object-in-javascript)

Comment: What testing framework are you using?

Comment: We're using Jasmine.

Comment: See See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22365796/simulate-drop-file-event/22821890#22821890 , http://dev.w3.org/2006/webapi/FileAPI/