# How do I simulate a file drag-n-drop upload via Chrome Extension?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension, drag-and-drop

I need to simulate a user dragging and dropping images onto a  file-upload `div`.  I'll be pulling the images from an `aws s3 bucket`.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22365796/simulate-drop-file-event) covers how to simulate the event. However, the `drop` is accomplished by invoking the `.drop()` event on the dropzone `div`.

However, in my case, the code will be run in a `content script` injected by a Chrome extension.  This means, afaik, I can't invoke the `drop()` method on the page's dropzone `div`.

Is there another way to simulate the `drag-and-drop` function?

If it matters, the page I'm dealing with appears to be using `jQuery UI ddmanager` to control its file dropzone `div`.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check and try the code sample of existing drag and drop given in [Passing multiple files with drag and drop](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2012/07/Drag-and-drop-a-folder-onto-Chrome-now-available#passing_multiple_files_with_drag_and_drop) wherein you can actually drag and drop a file or files from the desktop to your browser.

```
<div id=”dropzone”></div>

var dropzone = document.getElementById('dropzone');
dropzone.ondrop = function(e) {
  var length = e.dataTransfer.files.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    var file = e.dataTransfer.files[i];
    ... // do whatever you want
  }
};
```

However, it's also stated that when you try to pass a folder, notice that it will be either rejected or treated as a File object resulting in a failure. For folders, you need to change the way you handle dropped objects.

You may want to also read [Exploring the FileSystem APIs](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/) for further information regarding the FileSystem API and also regarding new drag and drop capability, read this [document](https://wiki.whatwg.org/wiki/DragAndDropEntries).

Lastly, these GitHub posts might also help:

- [drag_and_drop_helper.js](https://gist.github.com/rcorreia/2362544)
- [jquery.simulate.js](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-simulate/blob/master/jquery.simulate.js)

Comment: I don't see how your answer is relevant to the question. It does not concern Selenium in any way. It may be helpful (mentioned workaround sounds promising), but needs to be refocused / include more relevant info in the answer.